# File system gets stuck in 'FileSystemObject.DeleteFile'

Tags: windows, vb6, filesystems, delete-file

I have one automation project which does the job of building the setup using NSIS wrapper. The project is built with the VB6 code. During the execution of the project I am getting the error for deleting a file as “Method 'DeleteFile' of object 'IFileSystem3' failed” for the method ‘FileSystemObject.DeleteFile’ with force option set to true.

**Scenario:**

Server (Windows server 2012) drive is mapped to the local windows 7 system and whole operation is run in this mapped drive in client machine. And the project is run on the client machine.

Now when I run my project to build the setup, it copies all the application files to a folder called Temp under build1 and build2 directory and then it builds 2 separate setup exe using the NSIS (makeNSIS). After the creation of NSIS setups, it will delete all the source files from temp folder. While deleting the MDAC_TYP.exe file, I get the error as mentioned above. The above said error comes for both the Build1 & Build2 folders and the error comes occasionally (not every time) for the same exe.

I cannot rename/delete/move the file in any of the PC through UNC or even in server it cannot be deleted. If I try to rename/delete the file or its parent folder, the system from where I try to delete/rename gets stuck.

**Other methods I tried are as below.**

- Tried my project under testing environment and there was no such error.
- Checked for file handle using process explorer in both client as well as server – No handles were found
- Checked for Open files in the Shared folders of the server. - No open file connection found for the file.
- Tried rebooting the client machine – Not solved.
- Tried to delete/Rename the file using command in server – Not possible.
- Tried to delete/rename the file in server – No error and no message. Instead, server gets stuck.
- Checked for disk problems using chkdisk in server. No problems reported.
- Folder permission – The user ha full permission and there is no issue.
- Tried running the same build process after reboot – Everything works fine. But, again repeats after some time/day.
- Tried disconnecting the mapped drive at the time of error exists. But, still not able to rename.
- No antivirus/Event viewer log in both client as well as server

After all these still I could not able to explain why exactly the error occurring.

**Update:**

I recently noticed that the same error also occurs when deleting the file msstdfmt.dll

**Update 2:**

I also got error for the ms word file, error is same. In all the 3 cases i found that there is only a common thing that is all 3 files has read-only attribute.

Comment: `MDAC_TYP.EXE` is obsolete.  You'd only conditionally use this to deploy to an OS prior to Windows 2000 SP3.  No telling what is going on from your description, but using this file at all suggests you need more help than we can give here.  Seek a professional developer or at least a deployment specialist.

Comment: Yes i already put up the request to check this exe (why, how & when it is used) with the developer. But in my situation here i only copy this exe initially and delete this exe at the end of the setup creation using NSIS. but when i delete this exe i get the error